# jQuery WebMethod Parse Error

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I seem to be having issues calling a WebMethod from jQuery, I am using this article as my starting point:

http://www.misfitgeek.com/2011/05/calling-web-service-page-methods-with-jquery/

**JS**

```
    function WebMethod(fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) 
     {
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------+
        // Create list of parameters in the form:                               |
        // {'paramName1':'paramValue1','paramName2':'paramValue2'}              |
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------+
        var paramList = '';
        if (paramArray.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
                if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';
                paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i + 1] + '"';
            }
        }

        paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------+
        // Call the WEB method                                                  |
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------+
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ContractView.aspx' + '/' + fn,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: paramList,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: successFn,
            error: errorFn
        });
    };
```

I am passing into this method like this:

```
    $(".editableField").keydown(function(e) {

                    WebMethod('PriceContract',
                            [
                             'AQ', aq.val(),
                             'SOQ', soq.val()
                            ], updateTextFields, failed);

        });
```

**C#** (Note these are test methods, ignore the logic..)

```
     [WebMethod]
        public static ContractsListPricing PriceContract(string AQ, string SOQ)
        {
            ContractsListPricing clp = new ContractsListPricing();

           // clp.Aq = nAQ * 2;
           // clp.Soq = nSOQ * 2;

            return clp;
        }
```

When debugging the JS the paramList seems to be correct JSON (or so I believe):

> {"AQ":"140000","SOQ":"1169"}

This is resulting in a parseerror and I'm unsure why.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think that is not the correct JSON. the JSON should have keys with out single quots and values must be in quotes. Remove quotes from the key variable 'AQ' and 'SOQ' and try

Comment: Have you tried building the paramlist as an object rather than a string? Something like: `paramsList[paramArray[i]] = paramArray[i+1]`? According to the $.ajax() doc it should be serialized properly by jQuery before sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh no, please never build JSON manually by using string manipulation as you did. That's absolutely horrible. Take a look at [this article](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/).

Here's the correct way:

```
function WebMethod(fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) {
    var paramList = { };
    if (paramArray.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
            paramList[paramArray[i]] = paramArray[i + 1];
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ContractView.aspx' + '/' + fn,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(paramList),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });
}
```

Notice the usage of the `JSON.stringify` method to properly JSON encode the `paramList` object. This method is natively built into modern browsers. If you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script to your page.

Comment: I was having all sorts of conflicts using the JSON library so I decided to use the  jquery-json library and data: $.toJSON(paramList), which gives me the following JSON {"AQ":"140000","SOQ":"1169"} which still results in an 'invalid JSON' error.  Why would the json library return incorrect JSON?